# JSON array empty or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array, `var st = { "itema":{...},"itemb":[{"id":"s01","cd":"c01","dd":"d01",....}{"id":"s02","cd":"c02","dd":"d02",....}]}`
How to check st is empty or not?

Comment: Have you search in [Google](http://google.com) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` to see whether there are any object properties:

```
if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(st).length === 0) {
  // no properties
}
```

Now, if there *are* properties, it's up to you to decide whether an object with properties whose values are `undefined` or `null` is "empty" or not.

Another approach that might more closely reflect your concept of "empty" would be to stringify the object as JSON:

```
var __EMPTY = JSON.stringify({});
// ...
if (JSON.stringify(st) === __EMPTY) {
  // ...
}
```

Not the most efficient thing to do of course if your object might be relatively large in common cases.

The concept of an "empty object" really isn't very natural in JavaScript, at least in my experience.